# Get the index in an array of a clicked element in actionscript

Tags: arrays, actionscript

I'm trying to create a virtual keyboard.

I have a class `VirtualKeyboard` which contains an array called keyboard of 26 movieclips, each one representing a letter.

In the main class, I create an object of the class `VirtualKeyboard` and added an `eventlistener` on it when a letter is clicked.

I tried this in the event handler:

```
var objectClicked:Object = event.currentTarget;
var index:uint = virtualKeyboard.keyboard.indexOf(objectClicked);
```

But the `index` always returns the value 4294967295.

How can I know which letter was clicked, I mean the index in the keyboard array corresponding to that letter?

The same code is working correctly if I put it in the `VirtualKeyboard` class, but not from the main class.

Answer (score 3):

`4294967295` is 2^32 - 1. That is what happens when you assign -1 to a `uint`. It means the value was not found.

Recommendations:

- As indexOf returns an int, use int. It's faster anyway.
- Use Vectors if you can, that way you can be sure that everything is of the same class.
- Is `virtualKeyboard.keyboard` an array of DisplayObjects, or is it an array of strings or numbers? You have to make sure you are comparing apples to apples, not apples to goats (Also why I recommend Vector).
- Don't cast to Object. AS3 has a solid type system -- use it.